# Sql data type date showing time as well

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I made a DB and have a few tables with dates like joining dates, register date etc so once I select all those table inside SQL it shows me date which it should but since this DB is connected to winforms application and if I fetch any of those tables data on a textbox, gridview or reportviewer it shows me date but with a default time which it shouldn't.

Is there something that I need to do once I connect it to my Winforms application?

One of my table with date:

```
CREATE TABLE Admin_Details 
(
    Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    First_Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Last_Name VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    Login_User_Name VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    Login_Password VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
    Father_Name VARCHAR(20) NULL,
    Joining_Date DATE NOT NULL
)
```

I just want the see date in textbox, gridview and reports and remove time from it.

I have googled it and looked for answers here but couldn't find it anywhere.
I believe this is a very basic thing that's why it's not there but I really want to know this so if anyone knows if this is answered anywhere before so please share the link.

Answer (score 0):

The Sql Server equivalent `C#` object is `DateTime` type. There is no Date type in C#. That is why you have a default time with the date.

If you want to display the date only then you can do this before setting the value in the text box: `yourObject.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Comment: He have already mentioned this '*it shows me date but with a default time*'. And yes if you have a `DateTime` object there is a time part to it which always have value.

Comment: I see.
I knew that's something basic.

Comment: I'll go on and try this and start fixing up everything I did wrong.

Comment: You can store only date or date time in Sql Server. So I do not think it is the database which is causing the issue. His data type in the DB is of Date *'Joining_Date date NOT NULL'*

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks for the help Rahataur. Did I miss something while asking like should I change how I ask my questions, Raymond?

Comment: @Namaloom Glad if it helped you. Hope you don't mind accepting the answer as a solution and up vote if it solves the problem?

Comment: Yes, Rahataur. Everything is fine in sql DB. I mean if I create a new table and fetch the data I'll only see date which is what I want but if I do the same with winform/C# application then I'll get time as well so what you informed me about the case must be true.

Comment: Yes. Once it works then I'll do so.
also this "yourObject"  here do I need to create an object in C# for my date?

Comment: Right, I do.
I was trying this but I get the error saying:
"No overload for method ToString takes 2 arguments"
I tried this:
metrotextbox7.Text = dr[7].ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

P.S. I had to include System.Globalization library for Culture.info

Comment: @Namaloom Did it work after you added the namespaces?

Comment: No, it didn't.
I only included this namespace:
System.Globalization
And even after adding this namespace I'm getting this error:
"No overload for method ToString takes 2 arguments"